# How can I use template specialisation to find member function argument types etc?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm sure I've seen this described before but can't for the life of me find it now.

Given a class with a member function of some form, eg:

```
int Foo::Bar(char, double)
```

How can I use a template and various specialisations to deduce the constituent types, eg:

```
template<typename Sig>
struct Types;

// specialisation for member function with 1 arg
template<typename RetType, typename ClassType, etc...>
struct Types<RetType (ClassType::*MemFunc)(Arg0)>
{
    typedef RetType return_type;
    typedef ClassType class_type;
    typedef MemFunc mem_func;
    typedef Arg0 argument_0;
    etc...
};

// specialisation for member function with 2 args
template<typename RetType, typename ClassType, etc...>
struct Types<RetType (ClassType::*MemFunc)(Arg0, Arg1)>
{
    typedef RetType return_type;
    typedef ClassType class_type;
    typedef MemFunc mem_func;
    typedef Arg0 argument_0;
    typedef Arg0 argument_1;
    etc...
};
```

Such that when I instantiate Types with my above member function, eg:

```
Types<&Foo::Bar>
```

it resolves to the correct specialisation, and will declare the relevant typedefs?

Edit:

I'm playing around with fast-delegates with the callback statically bound to a member function.

I have the following mockup which I believe does statically bind to the member function:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class class_t, void (class_t::*mem_func_t)()>
struct cb
{
    cb( class_t *obj_ )
        : _obj(obj_)
    { }

    void operator()()
    {
      (_obj->*mem_func_t)();
    }

    class_t *_obj;
};

struct app
{
  void cb()
  {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  typedef cb < app, &app::cb > app_cb;

  app* foo = new app;
  app_cb f ( foo );
  f();
}
```

However - how to get this as a specialisation in the manner above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it, except that extra `MemFunc`, which is not part of the type.

```
template<typename RetType, typename ClassType, typename Arg0>
struct Types<RetType (ClassType::*)(Arg0)>   // <-- no MemType
{
    typedef RetType return_type;
    typedef ClassType class_type;
//  typedef MemFunc mem_func;     // <-- remove this line
    typedef Arg0 argument_0;
};
```

---

Nevertheless, you *cannot* use

```
Types<&Foo::Bar>
```

because Foo::Bar is a member function pointer, not the type of it. You'll need some compiler extensions to get the type in C++03, e.g. [`typeof` in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) or [Boost.Typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/typeof.html):

```
Types<typeof(&Foo::Bar)>
```

or upgrade to C++11 and use the standard [`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype):

```
Types<decltype(&Foo::Bar)>
```

Comment: unfortunately the whole point of this exercise is that I want to statically bind to a member function, so that the optimizer can optimize through the function pointer boundary, so to speak. Will using decltype allow me to achieve this?

Comment: `decltype` only returns the type of the object, not the pointer itself. Are you trying to make a [fast delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ImpossiblyFastCppDelegate.aspx)?