# How to convert a function or member function pointer in template arguments to a function class?

Tags: c++, templates

How to convert a function or member function pointer in template arguments to a function class? Let's say a function class is a class which defines member function `operator()`.

I think it is useful to generalize the use of function and member function in templates.

For example,

```
template<..., class FunClass>
class MyClass {};
```

Then, FunClass can be converted from all kinds of function pointers, member functions pointers with different number of arguments according to the requirements of MyClass. Any easy way to do the conversion? Thanks.

Comment: What's a "function class"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by convert - can you give some psuedo code example as to what exactly you mean to achieve?

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Do you want something like `std::function<Signature>`?

Comment: Actually, your code already contains almost complete `ConvertToFunClass`, you just need to extract it into a separate template.

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comments: you can extract `ConvertToFunClass` this way: (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8932845/276994))

```
template<typename Sig>
struct Types;

template<typename RetType, typename ClassType, typename Arg0>
struct Types<RetType (ClassType::*)(Arg0)>
{
    typedef RetType return_type;
    typedef ClassType class_type;
    typedef Arg0 argument_0;
};
```

Usage could be `MyClass<T, R, Types<decltype(&MyFun)>::ClassType > a;`.

(Disclaimer: I didn't try the code, have no access to compiler ATM.)